# Our server is launching brute force attacks on other websites, please advise

Tags: linux, security

Misc Situation:

-Server login is obtained by hacker, hacker places malicious brute force file in /hacked/bruteforce/

-Server password is then changed, hacker can still run script by navigating to their file on the server which will run upon their request (I am assuming?)

Question:

Would a combination of changing the server login password as well as adding a password protected .htaccess file to / stop the hacker in their tracks? Or can an .htaccess still be avoided in terms of rerunning the hacker's script?

I am very new to server security but am eager to learn anything and everything anyone can tell me! I highly appreciate any and all advice. Any recommended knowledge resources would also be fully utilised!

OUR SITUATION:

Here is the information provided to us by our host.

your Server/Customer with the IP: * has attacked one of our servers/partners. The attackers used the method/service: bruteforcelogin on: Sat, 14 Nov 2015 -exact time provided here-. The time listed is from the server-time of the Blocklist-user who submitted the report. The attack was reported to the Blocklist.de-System on: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 -exact time provided here-

Here is some more:

Lines containing IP-ip here-: NOT SORTED (from many different Machines)! DESTINATION-IP: -ip info here-

DESTINATION-IPs: -ip info here-

-ip here- - - [14/Nov/2015:-exact time provided here-] "POST wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4366 "referer-domain.tld" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"

-ip here- - - [14/Nov/2015:-exact time provided here-] "POST /wp-login.php .... truncated .... 0"POST wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4366 "referer-domain.tld" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"

-ip here- - - [14/Nov/2015:-exact time provided here-] "POST wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5117 "referer-domain.tld" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"

Regards, Jay.

Comment: [Nuke it from orbit.](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: It is nearly impossible to re-secure a server after a significant compromise like this. You need to erase it and rebuild. Read the question David linked for details.